# strongloop installation stuck at loadDep:sl-blip->network

Tags: npm, strongloop

I am trying to install strongloop in my ubuntu system as the docs suggest by

```
npm i -g strongloop
```

Now for almost an hour it's stuck with the line showing

```
loadDep:sl-blip -> networ
```

the spinner is spinning but that text doesn't change nor the progressbar shows any movement. is there a way to somehow debug or fix this?

Comment: With these types of questions, it is often helpful to include the version of node and npm you are using :-)

Comment: node: 4.2.1        npm: 3.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was likely caused by being behind a restrictive corporate firewall which prevented the optional non-registry dependency on sl-blip. Since this has been removed in the latest release (v6.0.1), this should no longer be a problem.

*disclaimer: I published v6.0.1 specifically to address this issue*